# Creating an Array From Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code, that is doing some if's, but with the values I am struggling to see how I create, and add the values to an array. At the moment, I am just adding the values to a listbox

```
List(lC, 0) = sh1.Cells(row, 23)
```

I tried creating an integer and, and then used something like

```
var = var & List(lC, 0) = sh1.Cells(row, 23)
```

But I am not sure if that's the correct way?

```
  Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim sh1
    Dim LR
    Dim lC
    Dim row


    Me.lstUsedRooms.Clear

    Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(4) 'room order from sheets
        With sh1
            LR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        End With

        lC = 0

        With Me.lstUsedRooms
            .ColumnCount = 1 'there is 8 columns
            .RowSource = ""
            .ColumnWidths = 40

        For row = 2 To LR


            NewIVTime = Format("14:00", "h:mm:ss")

                If Left(sh1.Cells(row, 6), 10) = "24/05/2019" Then   ' Gets all interviews for the date specified
                         Dim LTime As Date
                         Dim LTime1 As Date
                         LTime = Format(sh1.Cells(row, 7), "h:mm:ss") 'Gets the times from all the rooms from the date stated above
                         LTime1 = CDate(LTime) + 3 / 24 ' Adds 3 hours to the time above

                         If LTime1 < NewIVTime Then  ' Check which interviews display three hours after the new interview

                            .AddItem
                            .List(lC, 0) = sh1.Cells(row, 23)

                            lC = lC + 1

                        End If

                End If

            Next

            If .ListCount = 0 Then
                Me.lstUsedRooms.ColumnWidths = 100
                Me.lstUsedRooms.AddItem "No Rooms"
            End If


        End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Have a look at `ReDim Preserve`. That should give you an idea on how to create and array and add items to an array

Answer (score 0):

First see what you are going to be inputting, if you only need a 1 dimensional array then the best option is a collection:
    Dim newCollection as New Collection

```
For each r in Range

newCollection.Add Value 'Add value here 

Next r
```

If you are needing a multidimensional array then the array function is the best way:
    Dim zArray() as variant 
    Redim zArray(x, y, ...) 'x and y are size of array
Or 
    Redim Preserve zArray(x, y, ...) 'If you loop through the Redim

```
For i = 1 to x
For j = 1 to y

zArray(x,y)

Next j
Next i
```